# jQuery fancyBox not working with caption script

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Hello Everyone :) 
I am using jQuery [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) for display image/video gallery and [Capty](http://wbotelhos.com/capty) script for display image title on image.
Now I have combine both script but stuck at one point. When title is display on image fancyBox is not working. May be it is covering fancyBox HTML elements.

My Sample: http://goo.gl/puFzeW

I will thankful If anyone can help me. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css

```
.capty-caption {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zMQXt/8/

To make it work on IE use  plugin

https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Comment: very good, however this doesn't work on IE (versions 10 and lower I believe), which is an issue if you care about cross-browser compatibility (you should.) The OP still needs a javascript fallback solution.

Comment: @JFK added the solution :)

Comment: @Manish hey can you explain me how to use `Pointer Events Polyfill` in this example. I am facing same problem. I have check this fiddle but in IE not working.

Comment: @Rajnikanth download and use it in your page (https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill/blob/master/pointer_events_polyfill.js) . Then in Document ready paste this line  PointerEventsPolyfill.initialize({}); . i have checked in internet explorer its working after using the js

Comment: @Manish Hi I have created another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMQXt/9/) and I checked in IE9 and lightbox is not working. Can you please take a look in my JSFiddle.